# how to decide the forecasting method from the ME, MAD, MSE, SDE?

Tags: forecasting

how to decide the forecasting method from the ME, MAD, MSE, SDE?
for example, there is 4 methods that will be decide.
but, the value won't be always greater or smaller among the error of each other.
so, how can I decide the method of that forecast methods?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This is better suited to [stats.stackoverflow.com](http://stats.stackoverflow.com).

Don't use ME (mean error) as it doesn't measure accuracy, only bias.

Use MAD (mean absolute deviation) if you want forecasts that are the medians of the future distributions conditional on past observations.

Use MSE (mean squared error) if you want forecasts that are the means of the future distributions conditional on past observations.

SDE (standard deviation of errors) is just the square root of the MSE.